# File access in Net Core running on Full Net Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a net core app now running on full net452 framework. I have included a file (test.txt) in wwwroot that needs to be accessed from the net452 libraries. I have injected the hosting environment and gotten the path. However, System.IO.File.Exists(path\filename) returns false and the dll code returns "Specified file does not exist." The file does exist and the path "C:\Users\bbrown\Source\Repos\MyRepo\wwwroot\test.txt" looks correct. I am 99% certain that it is a permissions problem. A straight net452 app with path of "C:\Users\bbrown\Documents\TestApp\AppData\test.txt" works.

How can I gain access to the file or at least debug the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, what's the path that you're trying to find it in? Remember that `IHostingEvironment.ContentRootPath` is not `wwwroot` - it is one level up.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you have proper permission for that folder. Go to that folder under security and see if you have permission or not. If you are using IIS then make sure that your application pool user has a permission on that folder.

2) _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath will give you the content root path which means the folder itself. You should use _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath which will give you the path of wwwroot folder.

Here is the nice blog that will clear your doubts
https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/05/22/getting-the-web-root-path-and-the-content-root-path-in-asp-net-core